# How to read title and id from Blu-ray disc?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, blu-ray

Is it somehow possible to fetch Blu-Ray Disc id and title programmatically on Windows7+ platform?

Comment: There does not appear to be native support for Blu-ray built into Windows; you would have to use a 3rd party library.

Comment: @Luke: good to know, thanks. Would you suggest one 3rd party library in particular?

Comment: I don't know of any.  A quick Google search led to [this](http://www.videolan.org/developers/libbluray.html), but it cannot playback commercial discs so it might not be able to obtain the information.  If the disc is playing in some media player software then it might expose an API to get this information; I'm pretty sure Windows Media Player does this.

Comment: It seems that (according to MSDN) Windows Media Player 11 can't playback Blu-Ray discs. Anyways, thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can programmatically open the following files you'll probably get what you need:

/AACS/mcmf.xml - This file is the Managed Copy manifest file and will contain a 'contentID' attribute (in the mcmfManifest tag) that can be used to identify the disc.  Typically it is a 32 hexadecimal digit string.

There is sometimes, also an /CERTIFICATE/id.bdmv file which contains a 4 byte disc organization id (at byte offset 40) followed by a 16 byte disc id.

Sometimes, there is metadata information in the /BDMV/META/DL directory in the XML file bdmt_eng.xml (replace eng for other 3 letter language codes for other languages).  For example on the supplemetary disc of The Dark Knight I see this file contains:

```
<di:title><di:name>The Dark Knight Bonus Disc</di:name></di:title>
```

Comment: Interesting! I'd have some more questions, though: is contentID unique and thus does it let me identify the disc title uniquely? BTW, as far as I could notice id.bdmv and bdmt_LLL.xml are most of the times available only on decrypted discs, am I wrong?

Comment: As far as I'm aware contentID must be unique as it is the key that allows content authors to provide managed copy 'offers'.  Since managed copy is mandatory (but not yet available), any commercial disc produced after the deadline (Dec 2009?) must have a unique contentID.  However, I'm not aware of an available, public mapping to lookup a title from it's contentID.  As far as the other files go, they are available for reading on my linux box after simply mounting a Blu-ray disc for reading.  They don't require any sort of AACS decryption since they are not AV files.

Comment: After a little digging, the contentID is the ISAN number - see http://www.isan.org/docs/ISAN_in_Blu-ray_june_2010_S

Answer (score 0):

For .NET, the [BDInfo](http://www.cinemasquid.com/blu-ray/tools/bdinfo) library will parse the relevant disc structure.